# Jumpy scrolling of CollectionView with CABasicAnimation in cell

Tags: ios, performance, core-animation, uicollectionviewcell, cabasicanimation

I have a CollectionView in which the cell contains circular progress indicator view with CABasicAnimation.

```
func _animateShapeLayer(_ layer: CAShapeLayer, percent: CGFloat) {
        let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "strokeEnd")
        animation.fromValue = 0
        animation.toValue = percent
        animation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseOut)
        animation.duration = 1
        layer.add(animation, forKey: "animateStrokeEnd")
        layer.strokeEnd = percent
    }
```

This is causing scrolling jumpy. I have set should shouldRasterize to true for the cell as well as rasterizationScale set to main scale. Still its of no use. Help me please.

Comment: did you use time profiler to identify the problem, or to eliminate the possibility of this being simply a performance issue?

Comment: @Milan Nosáľ Yeah checked in instruments, with animation its 40 fps and without animation if I just set the stroke value its 50fps. If I remove setting the stroke value then it will boost it to 55fps.

Comment: Can you post a gif, showing the problem?